# what is the solution to a tridiagonal matrix in python?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, index-error

I'm working on a problem right now on tridiagonal matrix, i used the tridiagonal matrix algorithim in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm to implement a solution  and i have attempted it but my solution is not complete.

I'm confused and i need help also here is my script using jupyter notebook

```
import numpy as np 

# The diagonals and the solution vector 

b = np.array((5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5), dtype=float) # Main Diagonal
a= np.array((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), dtype = float) # Lower Diagonal
c = np.array((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), dtype = float) # Upper Diagonal
d = np.array((3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3), dtype = float) # Solution Vector

#number of rows 
n = d.size

newC = np.zeros(n, dtype= float)

newD = np.zeros(n, dtype = float)

x = np.zeros(n, dtype = float)

# the first coefficents 
newC[0] = c[0] / b[0]
newD[0] = d[0] / b[0]

for i in range(1, n - 1):
newC[i] = c[i] / (b[i] - a[i] * newC[i - 1])

for i in range(1, n -1):
newD[i] = (d[i] - a[i] * newD[i - 1]) / (b[i] - a[i] * newC[i - 1])

x[n - 1] = newD[n - 1]

for i in reversed(range(0, n - 1)):
    x[i] = newD[i] - newC[i] * x[i + 1]


x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors `a` and `c` should be the same length as `b` and `d`, so just prepend/append zero the them respectively. Additionally, the range should be `range(1,n)` otherwise your last solution element is `0` when it shouldn't be. You can see this modified code, as well as a comparison to a known algorithm, showing that it gets the same answer.

```
import numpy as np 

# The diagonals and the solution vector 

b = np.array((5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5), dtype=float) # Main Diagonal
a= np.array((0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), dtype = float) # Lower Diagonal
c = np.array((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), dtype = float) # Upper Diagonal
d = np.array((3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3), dtype = float) # Solution Vector

print(b.size)
print(a.size)

#number of rows 
n = d.size

newC = np.zeros(n, dtype= float)

newD = np.zeros(n, dtype = float)

x = np.zeros(n, dtype = float)

# the first coefficents 
newC[0] = c[0] / b[0]
newD[0] = d[0] / b[0]

for i in range(1, n):
    newC[i] = c[i] / (b[i] - a[i] * newC[i - 1])

for i in range(1, n):
    newD[i] = (d[i] - a[i] * newD[i - 1]) / (b[i] - a[i] * newC[i - 1])

x[n - 1] = newD[n - 1]

for i in reversed(range(0, n - 1)):
    x[i] = newD[i] - newC[i] * x[i + 1]

# Test with know algorithme
mat = np.zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    mat[i,i] = b[i]
    if i < n-1:
        mat[i, i+1] = a[i+1]
        mat[i+1, i] = c[i]

print(mat)

sol = np.linalg.solve(mat, d)
print(x)
print(sol)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because of how `a, b, c` and `d` are defined in the wikipedia article. If you look carefully, you'll see that the first element of `a` is `a2`, also the loop for `newD` goes to `n`. So, to have understandable indices to the arrays, i suggest you add a phantom element `a1`. And you get:

```py
import numpy as np 

# The diagonals and the solution vector 

b = np.array((5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5), dtype=float) # Main Diagonal
a = np.array((np.nan, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), dtype = float) # Lower Diagonal
                                                              # with added a1 element
c = np.array((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), dtype = float) # Upper Diagonal
d = np.array((3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3), dtype = float) # Solution Vector

#number of rows 
n = d.size

newC = np.zeros(n, dtype= float)

newD = np.zeros(n, dtype = float)

x = np.zeros(n, dtype = float)

# the first coefficents 
newC[0] = c[0] / b[0]
newD[0] = d[0] / b[0]

for i in range(1, n - 1):
    newC[i] = c[i] / (b[i] - a[i] * newC[i - 1])

for i in range(1, n):  # Add the last iteration `n`
    newD[i] = (d[i] - a[i] * newD[i - 1]) / (b[i] - a[i] * newC[i - 1])

x[n - 1] = newD[n - 1]

for i in reversed(range(0, n - 1)):
    x[i] = newD[i] - newC[i] * x[i + 1]


x
```